# Why is my header not accounting for a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, sass, haml

For some reason my header is not accounting for the scroll bar and is adding px to the right side. But only for my header.

I have no CSS but setting up text.

I set up my media queries so my header file looks like this

```
/* Basic Header Styles
  ======================= */
header {

  /* Mobile Exlusive Styles
  ============================ */
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  }

  /* Ipad to Desktop Styles
  ============================ */
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  }

  /* Desktop to LG Styles
  ========================== */
  @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

  }

  /* LG > Styles
  ================= */
  @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

  }

}
```

and my header markup is as follows:

```
.header-logo
  %ul
    %li
      = image_tag 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mikaimages/Logo.png', :alt => 'Tree Logo', :id => 'main-logo'

    %li
      %h1 Mika Kalathil
%nav
  %ul
    %li
      =link_to 'Home', root_path, :class => is_active?('home')

    %li
      =link_to 'About', about_path, :class => is_active?('about')

    %li
      =link_to 'Projects', projects_path, :class => is_active?('index')

    %li
      =link_to 'Contact' , contact_path, :class => "#{is_active?('contact')}"
```

here is a fiddle showing off my current site and what is happening. http://jsfiddle.net/RVPKL/

Comment: Your `header` has `row` class with `margin-left` and `margin-right`: -15px. You can remove this class.

Comment: Right I forgot I'm not using bootstrap anymore thanks!

Comment: There is really an awful lot of repetition in your CSS. How many reset stylesheets did you copy in there?

Comment: right I forgot to remove Bootstrap thanks! bootstrap has reset built in and I'm using one because I was supposed to remove BS!